# Magento 2.4.2 System configuration pdf disallowed

Tags: magento2.4.2, third-party-module

MagestyApps/module-web-images https://github.com/MagestyApps/module-web-images module   Upload SVG and WebP images in conflict System configuration pdf disallowed facing issue.

Answer (score 0):

> app/code/MagestyApps/WebImages/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
 /**
  * Copyright © 2021 MagestyApps. All rights reserved.
  * See LICENSE.txt for license details.
  */
  -->
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
<default>
    <magestyapps_webimages>
        <extensions>
            <vector>
                <svg>svg</svg>
                <svg_xml>svg+xml</svg_xml>
            </vector>
            <web_image>
                <webp>webp</webp>
                <pdf>pdf</pdf>
            </web_image>
        </extensions>
    </magestyapps_webimages>
    <dev>
        <image>
            <adapters>
                <GD2>
                    <class>MagestyApps\WebImages\Model\Image\Adapter\Gd2Rewrite</class>
                </GD2>
            </adapters>
        </image>
    </dev>
</default>
```